# Turn Vector Into ones, zeros matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have a 1xn dimensional vector with values between 0 - 9 like this:

```
A = [4 3 7 9 0]
```

I want to convert this to an nx10 matrix like so:

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
     1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Where everything is zero, except for the column in the ith row represented by the ith element in the original vector A.

I can easily do this with a for loop:

```
newA = zeros(n,10);
for (i = 1:n)
    newA(i,A(i)) = 1;
end
A = newA;
```

But is there a vectorized way to do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = double(bsxfun(@eq, A(:)+1, 1:max(A)+1));
```

Or [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
result = full(sparse(1:numel(A), A+1, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `sub2ind`:

```
A = [4 3 7 9 0];
colIdx = A + 1; % indexing in matlab starts from 1
rowIdx = 1:length(A);
nRows = length(A);
nCols = max(colIdx);
B = zeros(nRows,nCols);
B(sub2ind([nRows nCols],rowIdx,colIdx)) = 1
```